# PHP pagination script

Tags: php, pagination, substr

```
$string = "This is my page content. This text will be paginated.";
$pageNo = "0";
$pieceLength = "12";  

$preparedForPrint = substr($string,$pageNo,$pieceLength);
```

what i want to do is if the 12th character is inside a word(the 12th character is not a space) i want to move my cursor 'till it finds a space an return that substring despite the fact that is more than 12 characters long. how can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
while ($string[$pieceLength]!=' ' || $string[$pieceLength]!='\n')
   $pieceLength++;

substr($string, $pageNo, $pieceLength);
```

Also consider php builtin [wordwrap](https://www.php.net/word_wrap)

Answer (score 4):

You can use strpos()

```
$pieceLength = strpos($string," ",12);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

Look at [strpos()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php); offset would be `$pieceLength`, but position returned is still from beginning of the haystack.